# How to notify Twilio when user opt-in/out using profile settings

Tags: php, twilio, sms

I am pretty new to Twilio. I am trying to implement opt-in/out functionality to one of my site. Messaging is working now.my application can send sms and when user reply with STOP, Twilio is opting user out and when user reply with START, Twilio is opting user back in and incoming webhook is working.
But my problem is,
The application allows user to update the opt-in/out preferences using profile form, they can opt in or out using it. If the user opted out replying with STOP key and opts back in using the profile form. Now how should application notify Twilio that the user has opted back in ?
The application knows that the user has opted back in or out and can update the database but Twilio does not know and will never send sms even if sms sending is tried.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If the user opts back in without responding `START`/`UNSTOP` to the number they originally opted out on, they will need to do that.

You can set-up your service to send them an email if they optin via webform - when they previously opt-out (i.e. opt-in out of band) and tell them to send START to the previous number they opted out of (which you can provide to them, say using the sms scheme), this way, you can instruct them how to re-opt in.

<a href="sms:+18025551212?&body=START>Re-opt In